Sample covariance is a multiple of sample variance?
Consider a vector $(z_1,\ldots, z_N)$ from which you take samples $(x_1,\ldots, x_n)$ of size $n<N$, where any $z_j$ can show up only once in the samples. I am given an estimator for $\mu=\bar{z}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^Nz_k$, the mean value of the vector, and I would like to find the variance of the estimator. The estimator is
$$M=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k$$
where $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ are uniformly, identically distributed random variables on $(z_1,\ldots, z_N)$. By linearity and the fact, that $X_1$ is uniformly distributed on the vector, you find
$$
\begin{aligned}
E[M]&=E[X_1]=\bar{z}\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Moreover, I was given the solution that
$$Var[M]=\frac{N-n}{n(N-1)}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N (z_k-\bar{z})^2$$
(Hereby, use the fact that $P(X_i=z_k,X_j=z_l)=\frac{1}{N(N-1)}$ and $E[X_iX_j]=\frac{1}{N(N-1)}\sum_{k,l=1, k\ne l}^Nz_kz_l$, since the $z_j$'s only show up once in the sample.)
On the other hand, I calculated
$$
\begin{aligned}
Var[X_1]&=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N(z_k-\bar{z})^2\\
\end{aligned}
$$
such that with the solution above, I find
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{N-n}{n(N-1)}Var[X_1]&=Var[M]\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}Var\left[\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}\left[\sum_{k=1}^nVar[X_k]+\sum_{k\ne l}Cov[X_k,X_l]\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{n}Var[X_1]+\frac{(n-1)}{n}Cov[X_1,X_2]\\
\end{aligned}$$
which implies
$$Cov[X_1,X_2]=-\frac{1}{N-1}Var[X_1]$$
However, I cannot find this equality when I put in the values of $Var[X_1]$ and $Cov[X_1,X_2]$, which are
$$
\begin{aligned}
Var[X_1]&=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N(z_k-\bar{z})^2\\
Cov[X_1,X_2]&=\frac{1}{N(N-1)}\sum_{k,l=1, k\ne l}^N(z_k-\bar{z})(z_l-\bar{z})
\end{aligned}
$$
Does the equality
$$\frac{1}{N(N-1)}\sum_{k,l=1, k\ne l}^N(z_k-\bar{z})(z_l-\bar{z})=-\frac{1}{N-1}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N(z_k-\bar{z})^2$$
really hold true for $\bar{z}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N z_k$?

$X_1, \ldots, X_n$ with $n < N$ is a random sample without replacement from $z_1, \ldots, z_N$. This has the same distribution as taking the first $n$ items from a permutation $X_1, \ldots, X_N$ of $z_1, \ldots, z_N$.
The sum $X_1 + \cdots + X_N$ is constant with value $z_1, \ldots, z_N$, so its variance is zero. Rewriting
$$0 = \text{Var}(X_1 + \cdots + X_N) = N \text{Var}(X_1) + N(N-1) \text{Cov}(X_1, X_2)$$
yields the desired equality
$$\text{Cov}(X_1, X_2) = -\frac{1}{N-1} \text{Var}(X_1).$$

Thank you, that's an interesting answer. Though, I only have $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ for $n<N$. Does that make a difference? (I have to think through that myself.)

Could you please also have a look at my answer and check if this is correct, too?

@user408858 Your answer is actually the same as mine.

I find
$$
\begin{aligned}
0&=(N\bar{z}-N\bar{z})^2\\
&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^Nz_k-N\bar{z}\right)^2\\
&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^N(z_k-\bar{z})\right)^2\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^N(z_k-\bar{z})^2+\sum_{k,l=1,k\ne l}^N(z_k-\bar{z})(z_l-\bar{z})
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore
$$\sum_{k,l=1,k\ne l}^N(z_k-\bar{z})(z_l-\bar{z})=-\sum_{k=1}^N(z_k-\bar{z})^2$$
For
$$
\begin{aligned}
Var[X_1]&=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N(z_k-\bar{z})^2\\
Cov[X_1,X_2]&=\frac{1}{N(N-1)}\sum_{k,l=1, k\ne l}^N(z_k-\bar{z})(z_l-\bar{z})
\end{aligned}
$$
this implies
$$Cov[X_1,X_2]=-\frac{1}{N-1}Var[X_1]$$
