$\frac{1}{N(N-1)}\sum_{k,l=1, k\ne l}^N(z_k-\bar{z})(z_l-\bar{z})=-\frac{1}{N-1}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N(z_k-\bar{z})^2$
Consider real numbers $z_1,\ldots, z_N$. Does the equality
$$\frac{1}{N(N-1)}\sum_{k,l=1, k\ne l}^N(z_k-\bar{z})(z_l-\bar{z})=-\frac{1}{N-1}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N(z_k-\bar{z})^2$$
hold true for $\bar{z}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N z_k$?

Any attempts at all?

Yes, another whole question and my brain is fried: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4991005/sample-covariance-is-a-multiple-of-sample-variance

@Pedro, could you have a look at my answer?

Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see meta

Remove $\frac{1}{N(N-1)}$ from each side of your equation.

Let $$y_k:=z_k-\bar z.$$ Then,
$$\sum_{k,l}y_ky_l=\left(\sum_ky_k\right)^2=0^2=0,$$
q.e.d.

I find
$$
\begin{aligned}
0&=(N\bar{z}-N\bar{z})^2\\
&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^Nz_k-N\bar{z}\right)^2\\
&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^N(z_k-\bar{z})\right)^2\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^N(z_k-\bar{z})^2+\sum_{k,l=1,k\ne l}^N(z_k-\bar{z})(z_l-\bar{z})
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore
$$\sum_{k,l=1,k\ne l}^N(z_k-\bar{z})(z_l-\bar{z})=-\sum_{k=1}^N(z_k-\bar{z})^2$$
Is that correct?
